# Active Admin plugin for Rails5 bug

Tags: activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a rails page that's being controlled by a controller:

```
def update(options={}, &block) {....... super }
```

and "wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)" is returned when super call gets executed. This never happened in Rail4. Any clues?

Comment: Please add a stack trace from your log.  I'm surprised this syntax works, I would expect `def update(options = {}, &block); ... super end`